# CSS variable override

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a very simple [codepen](https://codepen.io/shannonhochkins/pen/OJdWEyB) setup to try to outline what im trying to achieve.

I want to have a default css variable set controlling the hue of the colours, but at an element level, i want to be able to change colour based on an override, in this case `--h`:

```
:root {
    // use 50 if --h isn't defined
    --hue: var(--h, 50);
}

.a {
    background-color: hsl(var(--hue), 100%, 50%);
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.a.b {
    // should change the hsl value to use 180, but it's using 50
    --h: 180;
}
```

The above css (should) change the hue of the element that has the class `b` & `a`, however it's always resolving to the parent value of 50 for the second element.

The confusing part to me, is that by providing the fallback value within `.a` it works, but this isn't desireable as my actual theme css is much more complex:

```
background-color: hsl(var(--h, var(--hue)), 100%, 50%);
```

Comment: Just a  note: using * instead of :root produces different results - I believe because in the :root setting the value of --h is set at 50 as per @quentin answer whereas in the * setting it's not a numeric value, but the string value that applies to each element.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Comment: I posted, the exact code in the demo @rob

Comment: Again: a [mcve] Please read the link

Answer (score 1):

The value of `—-hue` is calculated using the value of `—-h` that applies to `:root`. It does not store the fact you are using `—-h` and then calculate it on the `.a.b` element where you have changed the value of `—-h`. (You could end up with infinite loops, which CSS tries to avoid making possible).

I don’t think there is a way to achieve when you want other than through approaches you’ve ruled out.

Comment: I thought so - was hoping there was a wizard solution i hadn't thought about - thanks anyways!

Comment: Changing :root to * seems to work, however Im not sure of performance / other implications - do you have any thoughts on this?

Comment: It's going to impact performance, but probably not substantially, and could screw things up depending on how you expect your styles to be inherited.

Comment: After a quick test - it's not what im after either as the variables are assigned to every element, so overriding the --hue value will only update the current element not it's siblings

Comment: That's what I meant with my comment about inheritance.

Comment: All good! Thanks for your help anyways :)